# I don't understand the logic of this section in the TwentySeventeen WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm learning about WordPress and going through some of the default themes to try and get a feeling for how they work. I came across this section in the TwentySeventeen theme (twentyseventeen/template-parts/page/content-front-page.php) and it confused me:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'twentyseventeen-featured-image' );

        $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );

        $thumbnail_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'twentyseventeen-featured-image' );

        // Calculate aspect ratio: h / w * 100%.
        $ratio = $thumbnail_attributes[2] / $thumbnail_attributes[1] * 100;
        ?>

        <div class="panel-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo esc_url( $thumbnail[0] ); ?>);">
            <div class="panel-image-prop" style="padding-top: <?php echo esc_attr( $ratio ); ?>%"></div>
        </div><!-- .panel-image -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm still a novice programmer, so maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I don't understand why the following two things happen:

1. Why is the $post_thumbnail_id variable created but never used? Why not create it right away instead of constantly calling get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID )?
2. $thumbnail and $thumbnail_attributes are the same, right? So why create both?

Wouldn't this make more sense:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :

        $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );

        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, 'twentyseventeen-featured-image' );

        // Calculate aspect ratio: h / w * 100%.
        $ratio = $thumbnail[2] / $thumbnail[1] * 100;
        ?>

        <div class="panel-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo esc_url( $thumbnail[0] ); ?>);">
            <div class="panel-image-prop" style="padding-top: <?php echo esc_attr( $ratio ); ?>%"></div>
        </div><!-- .panel-image -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

I created a child theme and used the above code instead of what was originally there and everything works fine. I guess I'm just scratching my head on why the original developers would code it that way, and from a student's perspective would like some insight.

Comment: Yes. Submit it to the https://core.trac.wordpress.org/.

Answer (score 0):

The original developer could have done:

```
$thumbnail_attributes = $thumbnail;
```

You'd have to ask the module developer why the didn't. I'd write it off to a brain fart.